# JavaFX dependency of windows in gui

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a rather big project for school with several windows in gui and whenever I run the program, it runs a method placed in a class that opens a window much later. How can I change so that it doesn't call that method which should be called later, when that window is shown.

Comment: Post some code of what you tried

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I fixed that problem but now I don't get it why the driver is not assigned correctly

```
package gui;

import java.time.LocalTime;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import model.Driver;
import model.Loading;
import service.Service;

public class SMSDialog extends Stage
{
    private Driver driver;

    public SMSDialog(String title, Driver driver)
    {
        System.out.println(driver);
        // initOwner(owner);
        initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        setMinHeight(100);
        setMinWidth(200);
        setResizable(false);

        setTitle(title);
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        initContent(pane);
        this.driver = driver;
        System.out.println(getDriver());

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        setScene(scene);

    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private TextArea txaMessage;

    private void initContent(GridPane pane)
    {
        // pane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        pane.setHgap(10);
        pane.setVgap(10);

        txaMessage = new TextArea();
        pane.add(txaMessage, 0, 0);
        txaMessage.setText("The expected end time of your loading is " + getEndTime());

        Button btnClose = new Button("Close");
        pane.add(btnClose, 0, 1);
        btnClose.setOnAction(event -> closeAction());
    }

    private LocalTime getEndTime()
    {
        Loading load = Service.getLoadings().get(0);

        System.out.println(getDriver());
        for (Loading l : Service.getLoadings())
        {

            if (l.getTruck().getNumber() == driver.getTruck().getNumber())
            {
                load = l;
                break;
            }
        }
        return load.getExpectedEndTime();
    }

    private void closeAction()
    {
        close();

    }

    public Driver getDriver()
    {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setDriver(Driver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
}
```

And I have this output:

```
Carl
null
Carl
```

Comment: Please edit your question if you have updates; this does not appear to be an answer to the original question.